# How can I run squid in cygwin

Tags: squid, cygwin

I've got cygwin installed on a windows machine & I'm trying to run squid. But when I run `/usr/sbin/squid -i` it does nothing, no response, no log files, nothing.  I've tried searching for solutions but all I've found is one particularly hostile thread on the squid maling list.  The [doco](http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v2/2.7/squid-2.7.STABLE9-RELEASENOTES.html#ss4.1) just says to run with the `-i` to install as a windows service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to run Squid in Cygwin; Guido Serassio maintains [binary installers for Windows](http://squid.acmeconsulting.it/), invlufi.  Try using one of those instead; it has the same exact interface as the Linux versions.

Comment: I must be blind, I can't see the installers on that link.

Comment: Link no longer works

Answer (score 4):

From [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/622583/8076), I found that I first needed to run `/usr/sbin/squid -z` and then `/usr/sbin/squid`.  Log files appear at `/var/log/squid/` after that.

Answer (score 3):

The references to acmeconsulting are no longer current. The commonly referenced page http://squid.acmeconsulting.it/index.html has Squid for Windows v2.7 which is sorely out of date from the current v3.1. On that page is a link for Squid for Windows v3.0. The information there is that due to issues with Bazaar, Squid for Windows is essentially a dead and outdated project. Further, there is no link for v3.x for Windows. Therefore, if you want anything more recent than 6 year old software on Windows, you need to either go for a Cygwin implementation, go virtual with a local VMware instance with *nix, or install on a low-cost cloud-based private server.

My approach:
I'm looking into the Cygwin solution now. If that doesn't work, I will progress on to a manually installed  VMware instance.  If that doesn't work I may try a pre-installed VMWare appliance (DansGuardian?), but only if I can get a personal-use version for free.  If that doesn't work, I'll accept that the internet is just slow and deal with it.  ;)

Other suggestions for Squid on Windows are welcome, but please, let's start deprecating all of these references to the fine work done at acmeconsulting - it's simply not valid anymore.

HTH

Comment: Have you got it working on Cygwin?

Comment: I am no longer using Cygwin or Squid. The notes here were posted 9 years ago. ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is a Squid MSI Installer at [GitHub Squid Windows Installer](https://github.com/diladele/squid3-windows). It is an open source project to ease installation of Squid on Windows. Currently it is based on Cygwin Squid 3.3.3; 3.5.1 version will be published soon.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this link](http://www.deckle.co.za/squid-users-guide/Starting_Squid).
You may be interested at first in the `-d` option.

You could also try to re-compile `squid` in *cygwin* (in setup.exe, install the development tools).

Answer (score 0):

Configure `/etc/resolv.conf` file . 
I found this problem with debug mode!

```
$ /usr/sbin/squid.exe -f squid.conf -d 5 -N
2017/02/13 17:47:56| Starting Squid Cache version 3.3.3 for x86_64-unknown-cygwin...
2017/02/13 17:47:56| Process ID 9848
2017/02/13 17:47:56| Process Roles: master worker
2017/02/13 17:47:56| With 3072 file descriptors available
2017/02/13 17:47:56| Initializing IP Cache...
2017/02/13 17:47:56| DNS Socket created at [::], FD 4
2017/02/13 17:47:56| DNS Socket created at 0.0.0.0, FD 5
2017/02/13 17:47:56| /etc/resolv.conf: (2) No such file or directory
2017/02/13 17:47:56| Warning: Could not find any nameservers. Trying to use localhost
2017/02/13 17:47:56| Please check your /etc/resolv.conf file
2017/02/13 17:47:56| or use the 'dns_nameservers' option in squid.conf.
2017/02/13 17:47:56| Logfile: opening log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log
2017/02/13 17:47:56| Logfile Daemon: opening log /var/log/squid/access.log
2017/02/13 17:47:56| WARNING: no_suid: setuid(0): (22) Invalid argument
2017/02/13 17:47:56| Store logging disabled
2017/02/13 17:47:56| Swap maxSize 0 + 262144 KB, estimated 20164 objects
2017/02/13 17:47:56| Target number of buckets: 1008
2017/02/13 17:47:56| Using 8192 Store buckets
2017/02/13 17:47:56| Max Mem  size: 262144 KB
2017/02/13 17:47:56| Max Swap size: 0 KB
2017/02/13 17:47:56| Using Least Load store dir selection
2017/02/13 17:47:56| Set Current Directory to /var/spool/squid
2017/02/13 17:47:56| Loaded Icons.
```